Synchronize two separate .GIFs to play at the same time without JS?
I'm working on creating a somewhat complex custom CSS page for Itch, which restricts me to using only CSS and HTML—no scripts allowed.
I'm facing an issue where I need two separate GIFs to play simultaneously. These GIFs have the same duration and are designed to complement each other, so syncing them is important. Unfortunately, combining them into a single GIF isn’t an option.
The problem lies in how browsers handle GIF loading:

GIF 1 often loads and starts playing faster than GIF 2, but this
behavior isn’t consistent—it varies across reloads.

Does anyone know if there’s a way to sync the playback of these GIFs or force them to start together using just HTML and CSS? I’m running out of ideas here, so I’d really appreciate any suggestions from a front-end expert.

AFAIK this is not possible, or at least not without JS. Your best bet might be to explore CSS animations, but I know very little about it and maybe even then it's still not possible without JS.

Can you use an iframe? If so, perhaps you could build a page, hosted somewhere else, which uses JS to preload your GIFs and render them simultaneously, then include that page in yours using an iframe.

@BrettDonald sadly not

You might try to preload your images.
Please read the article @ MDN


img {width:40vw}
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Image preload example</title>

  <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/animation/2023/05/20/21/52/21-52-42-295_512.gif" as="image" type="image/gif" />
  <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/animation/2024/01/28/21/36/21-36-44-257_512.gif" as="image" type="image/gif" />
  
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/animation/2023/05/20/21/52/21-52-42-295_512.gif" />
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/animation/2024/01/28/21/36/21-36-44-257_512.gif" />
</body>



